# how to append getRequestDispatcher with extra data in java?

Tags: java, servlets

So Basically I have:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/zips/packet.html").forward(request, response);
    return;
}
```

As you can you can see when a request is made for this servlet, It responds with `packet.html` file. To be precise, inside my `packet.html` I have a video element with `src=""` which I need to fill it by users requested url.

**Question:** How do I send a little extra data saying video source to the client, So in my client side it could change the video source from `src=""` to `src="actual video source"`

**I TRIED:**

```
String video_source = "/zips/video.mp4";
response.getWriter().append(video_source);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/zips/packet.html").forward(request, response);
```

With this method I can see my `packet.html` being received in my front-end But I can't find the `video_source`. FYI: don't know how to receive the `video_source`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, To satasify your demand you can follow many apporoaches. One approach that I would suggest would put into consideration whatever you've already started

As Below

Step 1.  Forward your request and response objects into packet.jsp,instead of into packet.html

Step 2. inside packet.jsp grab the input from user and send it with
   the request object from packet.jsp

Step 3. Write a servlet class that process the request object from 
   packet.jsp and send the video as mulitpart file with the response.

Moreover, Do some research on how to use jsp's and servlets

The second approach would be to write client side javascript code that send ajax request to grab the video in a second call. For this you might even consider some client side frameworks and libraries(like jquery, angular, etc) that ease your work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1. Pass that additional information via request attribute (request.setAttribute())
2. Use some dynamic handler (like a servlet or JSP) to serve /zips/handler.html
3. Use request.getAttribute() in that handler.

So:

in your initial servlet, put

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setAttribute("real_source", /*some real source*/);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/zips/packet.html").forward(request, response);
    return;
}

In your /zips/packet.html you just use request.getAttribute("real_source") to generate the html attribute you need.